# Using a subroutine's output as a variable in a separate subroutine

Tags: vba, excel

Basically what I'm trying to do here is use this sub:

```
Sub SelectFirstBlankCell()
Dim sourceCol As Integer, rowCount As Integer, currentRow As Integer
Dim currentRowValue As String

sourceCol = ActiveCell.Column   'Uses ActiveCell.Column as reference now, but needs to fit into each Subroutine to select next available
rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, sourceCol).End(xlUp).Row

'for every row, find the first blank cell and select it
For currentRow = 1 To rowCount
    currentRowValue = Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Value
    If IsEmpty(currentRowValue) Or currentRowValue = "" Then
        Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Select
        Exit For
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

To find the next empty cell in a column to input the string from this sub into.

```
Set selRange = Selection

For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
  If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
     If strApps = "" Then
      strApps = ListBox1.List(i)
      intAppCodeOffset = i
      strAppCodeVal = Worksheets("TestSheet").Range("B31").Offset(i, 0).Value
    Else
      strApps = strApps & ", " & ListBox1.List(i)
      intAppCodeOffset = i
      strAppCodeVal = strAppCodeVal & ", " & Worksheets("TestSheet").Range("B31").Offset(i, 0).Value
    End If
  End If
Next

Set selRange = selRange.Offset(1, 0)

With selRange
  selRange.Value = strAppCodeVal
End With
```

I've tried replacing `selRage.Offset(1, 0)` with `SelectFirstBlankCell`, but I get an object reference error every time. Any help would be greatly appreciated on this as I can't seem to find how to do it on here.

Comment: You're trying to set `selRange` with the name of a subroutine, which isn't valid syntax. It looks like what you're trying to do is have `SelectFirstBlankCell` return a value to `selRange`, so in that case you need it to be a `Function()` so that it returns a value.

Comment: I'd give [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) a read, then start over.

Comment: A parameter `Sub` procedure doesn't have an "output", it *does* something. Look into `Function` procedures for how you can *return* a value from a procedure, and/or how `ByRef` parameters can be used to that effect (although, a `Function` return value is much cleaner & idiomatic than using a `ByRef` parameter for output).

Comment: I don't see _any_ reference to `SelectFirstBlankCell` in your second block of code, so whether its a `Sub` or a `Function` is irrelevant - it's not being called. _NOTE:_ Once you do call it, it's important that it be a `Function` and return a `Range`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, try changing `Sub` to `Function`, like this:

```
Function SelectFirstBlankCell(sourceCol as Integer) as Range
```

(remove old sourceCol dim and assignment)

```
...
        Set SelectFirstBlankCell = Cells(currentRow, sourceCol)
...
End Function
```

Then you can do your change:

```
Set selRange = SelectFirstBlankCell(ActiveCell.Column) 'Or whatever you think should be defined as the sourceCol
```

Your code should probably not select anything itself, unless that is the end result of your macro. Try to use the code to directly manipulate the cells instead.